# Is it better to save the length of a list that I use several time?

Tags: python, list

I know about inlining, and from what I checked it is not done by the Python's compiler.

My question is : is there any optimizations with the python's compiler which transforms :

```
print myList.__len__()
for i in range(0, myList.__len__()):
    print i + myList.__len__()
```

to

```
l = myList.__len__()
print l
for i in range(0, l):
    print i + l
```

So is it done by the compiler ?
If it is not : is it worth it to do it by myself ?

Bonus question (not so related) : I like to have a lot of functions (better for readability IMHO)... like there is no inlining in Python is this something to avoid (lots of functions) ?

Comment: The Python compiler does practically no optimizations. You might want to look at [PyPy](http://pypy.org/) if you want a faster Python.

Comment: Please don't use one post to ask two different questions.

Comment: I'll take a look at PyPy and I won't forget Martijn Pieters's advice. Thanks. By the way I see in the answers that it is not done by the compiler but is it worth it to do it by myself ?

Comment: @mthpvg: of course it is worth doing it yourself, but don't optimize away readability unless you have a compelling reason to (e.g. evidence from profiling and / or tests with the `timeit` module).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there isn't. You can check what Python does by compiling the code to byte-code using the `dis` module:

```
>>> def test():
...     print myList.__len__()
...     for i in range(0, myList.__len__()):
...         print i + myList.__len__()
... 
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(test)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (myList)
              3 LOAD_ATTR                1 (__len__)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            0
              9 PRINT_ITEM          
             10 PRINT_NEWLINE       

  3          11 SETUP_LOOP              44 (to 58)
             14 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (range)
             17 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
             20 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (myList)
             23 LOAD_ATTR                1 (__len__)
             26 CALL_FUNCTION            0
             29 CALL_FUNCTION            2
             32 GET_ITER            
        >>   33 FOR_ITER                21 (to 57)
             36 STORE_FAST               0 (i)

  4          39 LOAD_FAST                0 (i)
             42 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (myList)
             45 LOAD_ATTR                1 (__len__)
             48 CALL_FUNCTION            0
             51 BINARY_ADD          
             52 PRINT_ITEM          
             53 PRINT_NEWLINE       
             54 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           33
        >>   57 POP_BLOCK           
        >>   58 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             61 RETURN_VALUE
```

As you can see, the `__len__` attribute is looked up and called each time.

Python cannot know what a given method will return between calls, the `__len__` method is no exception. If python were to try to optimize that by *assuming* the value returned would be the same between calls, you'd run into countless different problems, and we haven't even tried to use multi-threading yet.

Note that you would be much better off using `len(myList)`, and not call the `__len__()` hook directly:

```
print len(myList)
for i in xrange(len(myList):
    print i + len(myList)
```

Comment: As an addendum, there's no safe way the Python interpreter could combine multiple calls to `len`: since Python lists are mutable, a different thread could modify the list *while* the loop is executing, so `len` could return different values.

Comment: @scvalex: not just multi-threading problems, but the base assumption that `__len__` returns the length and it will not change is a false assumption, because Python is a dynamic language.

Answer (score 1):

No, the optimization you're asking about is not done by the CPython compiler. In fact hardly any optimizations are done by the CPython compiler.

To see for yourself, `import dis` and disassemble a function with code like you're asking about: `dis.dis(func)`.

The reason this isn't optimized is that it is entirely possible that an attribute (even a method like `__len__`)  will be a completely different object the next time it is accessed. This rarely happens, of course, but Python supports it.

Attribute access does consume time, so storing a reference to an attribute you will be using repeatedly (especially in a local variable) can make your code run faster. However, it decreases readability, so I'd wait until you know that a given piece of code is a bottleneck before applying it. In your case, the time spent printing is easily going to overwhelm the attribute access.

In the final analysis, if performance were paramount you'd be using something other than Python in the first place, no?